# How do I use the second elevator in the Channelwood area of realMyst?

Tags: realmyst

In the Channelwood area of [realMyst](https://cyan.com/games/realmyst/), I found the lever to open the top gate beside the second elevator, used it, and went down the spiral staircase to the bottom gate, but it didn't open. Is there something else I'm supposed to do to open it? I can't get out to redirect the water to use this second elevator.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: What is "real" Myst?

Comment: @RoijanEskor - realMyst is a remade enhanced graphics/sounds/mechanics version of Myst released back in the early 2000s - today there's yet another upgraded further enhanced version of Myst on steam called Myst: Masterpiece Edition - latest and greatest!

Comment: @johnabrams7 You forgot to mention that there's also an enhanced version of realMyst named realMyst Masterpiece Edition released in 2014 (meaning it's newer than Myst: Masterpiece Edition).

Comment: It's been a long time since I've played Myst/realMyst, but I believe there's another switch you have to hit somewhere to open that gate.

Comment: @Powerlord - Ah! I actually meant realMyst Masterpiece Edition - I wasn't aware there was also a Myst Masterpiece Edition.